# Observable.FromAsync what is IScheduler argument for?

Tags: c#, reactive, reactiveui

I was trying to execute that Reactive + ReactiveUI Code

`Observable.FromAsync(async () => //async code that must run on UI Thread, RxApp.MainThreadScheduler);`

But that doesn't get executed on MainUIThread.
Can anyone tell me what's the point of having IScheduler as parameter since it doesn't seem to get executed on UI?

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"M {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    using (var els = new EventLoopScheduler())
    {
        els.Schedule(() => Console.WriteLine($"ELS {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"));
        Observable.FromAsync(() => GetNumberAsync(1)).Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"S1 {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"));
        Observable.FromAsync(() => GetNumberAsync(2), els).Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"S2 {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

Task<int> GetNumberAsync(int run)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{run} GNA {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{run} TR {System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        return 42;
    });
}
```

I get an output like this:

```
M 1
ELS 20
1 GNA 1
2 GNA 1
1 TR 12
2 TR 13
S1 11
S2 20
```

You'll note that the `EventLoopScheduler` creates a thread with ID `20` and the continuation out of the `FromAsync` when using the `els` is run on that thread.

The scheduler isn't the one the task is run on, it's the one that the next operator in the pipeline executes using.

Comment: Oh I see. Then how can I force async method to run on the thread I want, in the middle of a Reactive query. Example:

`this.WhenAnyValue(p =>p.RandomObject)
.DistinctUntilChanged()
.ObserveOnDispatcher().Select(_ =>
            {
                var fn = async () =>
                {
                   ///Async Code Here
                };
                return fn().ToObservable();
            }).Concat().Subscribe()`

Comment: I wouldn't use `Select`/`Concat`.  And you should not need to use the `.ToObservable()`. It should be sufficient to use `.SelectMany(x => /* Aync code */)`.

Comment: My mistake, if the async method returns `Task` then you need `ToObservable()`.

Answer (score 0):

So I came with that solution:

```
Observable
...
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Select(_ => InvokingReturningTaskMethod().ToObservable())
            .Concat()
            .Subscribe()
```

That seems to be running on Dispatcher Thread
I wanted to find a better solution tho. Something that doesn't require to

```
InvokingReturningTaskMethod().ToObservable()
```